# PHP convert mysql_connection to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to convert code that uses mysql_connect to pdo, however I do not know what to do after this. should put in place "mysql_result".

```
$query = "select * from tbl_usuarios where login = '$cliente_username' and senha = '$cliente_password'";
$result = $conexao->query($query);
$number = $result->fetch();

if ($number==0) { ?><script>alert('Dados incorretos! Tente novamente.');</script>
<?php
    exit;
} else {
    $_SESSION['usuario_id'] = mysql_result($result,0,'id');
    $_SESSION['usuario_nome'] = mysql_result($result,0,'nome');
    ?><script>document.location = '../principal.php'</script><?php
}
mysql_close($conexao);  

} 
?>
```

Comment: solved  $_SESSION['usuario_id'] = $number['id'];
 $_SESSION['usuario_nome'] = $number['nome'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_result($result,0,'id')
```

becomes

```
$number->id
```

and

```
mysql_result($result,0,'nome')
```

becomes

```
$number->nome
```

maybe you should add a limit 1 to you query:

```
$query = "select * from tbl_usuarios where login = '$cliente_username' and senha = '$cliente_password' limit 1";
```